# Combobox + Radiobutton code not working

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textbox, radio-button

why doesn't my code work? I've tried coding it in 3 different events. 
Here are my codes and the form I am coding.[Textbox6 is the textbox beside the Block label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IVP8.png)

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
    Dim Course = ComboBox1.Text
    Dim Block = TextBox6.Text
    If Course = "BS Civil Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - D"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Electrical Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - C"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Electronics and Communications Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - G"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Industrial Engineering (E)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - E"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Industrial Engineering (F)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - F"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Mechanical Engineering (A)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - A"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Mechanical Engineering (B)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 -B"
    End If
End Sub
```

AND THIS

```
Private Sub RegistrationForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Course = ComboBox1.Text
    Dim Block = TextBox6.Text
    If Course = "BS Civil Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - D"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Electrical Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - C"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Electronics and Communications Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - G"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Industrial Engineering (E)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - E"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Industrial Engineering (F)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - F"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Mechanical Engineering (A)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - A"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Mechanical Engineering (B)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 -B"
    End If
```

AND THIS

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim Course = ComboBox1.Text
    Dim Block = TextBox6.Text
    If Course = "BS Civil Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - D"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Electrical Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - C"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Electronics and Communications Engineering" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - G"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Industrial Engineering (E)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - E"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Industrial Engineering (F)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - F"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Mechanical Engineering (A)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 - A"
    ElseIf Course = "BS Mechanical Engineering (B)" And RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Block = "3 -B"
    End If
End Sub
```

PS: I haven't code anything for the EVENING rb yet.

Comment: Set breakpoints, watch the code execute line by line.  It is not clear what you want to do or what "not working" means (that could describe almost all posts here) *but* the code doesnt do anything with `Block` after those gyrations - it just goes out of scope. Block is just a local variable, not a reference to `TextBox6`

Comment: Consider to re-think your logic. That's a really really bad design, be careful!